# Could not able to connect to with Elastic search cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup 2 nodes cluster for Elastic search.

cluster.name:test-cluster

node.name: es-node1

node.master: true
node.data: true

path.data: /es/data
path.logs: /es/log

network.host: privateIP

http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [PublicIP]

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

Comment: Are the two nodes on the same machine? What is the configuration of the second node?

Comment: no its  different machine.
same configuration except 
node.name:es-node2
privateIP
publicIP

Answer (score 2):

On node 1 you need to have this so that node 2 can see node 1

```
network.host: PublicIP-Node1
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [PublicIP-Node2]
```

Similarly, on node 2 you need to have this:

```
network.host: PublicIP-Node2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [PublicIP-Node1]
```

Comment: Note that it's also fine to have the node's own name in there. So for both you can just put [PublicIP-Node1, PublicIP-Node2] for ease of deployment.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the unicast.hosts settings can definitely include all nodes.